# Why is my Library_Dev database not shown in SQL Server Object Explorer( (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB )?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, localdb

The first thing I did is went to `appsettings.json` then I wrote that code:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "LibraryConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;DataBase=Library_Dev;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
```

Next I added this class using (`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; (DbContext)`):

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    DbSet<Person> person { get; set; }
}
```

`Person` class has properties but just ignore it.

Then I opened `Startup.cs` and in the `ConfigureServices` method I added:

```
services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibraryConnection")));
```

and of course I typed in Console Management Packages:

```
add-migration "Initial migration"
```

But I can't see the `Library_Dev` in SQL Server Object Explorer.

I'll be so thankful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

`Add-Migration` just adds the migrations to your project.
Next you need to run `Update-Database` to apply the migrations and scaffold the actual database.

More information on how to run the commands is presented in the following link:

[EF Core Migrations](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `startup`, when you run your project then database will create:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
      using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
      {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LibraryContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
      }
      ...
  }
```

Comment: I would refrain from using the database.migrate() inside of the application because it has a major limitation i,e "you should not be running multiple instances of the Migrate method at the same time" which might be the case if you are running multiple instances of the app.

Comment: `database.migrate()` is a normal way for update database for an application but of course it isn't useful for all scenario, and I didn't say it is a solution for all scenario, and also in this question didn't say that he want to run multiple instances.